# Panning a background image in all directions on mouseover using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, panning

I am trying to add a panning effect to background image in a page, the image is quite large 1800 x 1067 ,so basically will be larger than the window
I want to pan the background in all directions when the mouse reaches the end of the window only , 
I found a Javascript code that does the panning, but only horizontally , tried playing around with it to enable vertical panning. didnt work.

here is the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v662t/

// HTML

```
<div id="pageBg">
</div>
```

//CSS

```
#pageBg {
    background: url(images/pageBg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 768px;
    min-width: 1024px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;   
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

// Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#pageBg').mousemove(function(e){
      var mousePosX = (e.pageX/$(window).width())*100;
      $('#pageBg').css('background-position-x', mousePosX +'%');
   }); 
});
```

Comment: could you make a mock of the problem in a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `background-size: cover` and add a few javascript lines for mousePosY:

```
var mousePosY = (e.pageY/$(window).height())*100;
$('#pageBg').css('background-position-y', mousePosY +'%');
```

check out the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/georgedyer/XWnUA/2/

Comment: Great ! and thank you. I still have one more question: how can I make it only pan when it reaches the edges (say the final 50px of the window ) ?

Comment: See my other answer for panning on the edge.

Comment: what about vanilla JS? the question doesn't say Jquery but Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering the comment about panning at the edges here to include better formatting.

It depends on how *exactly* you want panning at the edges to work. Will the image move only if the mouse is moving over the edge, or even when the mouse is motionless but hovering over the edge?

In the first case: you can use the same fiddle code and just check to see if `mousePosX` or `mousePosY` are < 10 or > 90 (or whatever percentages you want to define as edges). If so, then instead of moving the image to a percentage of the window you'd move it to a percentage of the edge.

Since that may end up a little too sensitive, so you could go with the alternative of just moving on hover, in which case you'd use `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave` events instead, and just start an interval on `mouseEnter` (using `var interval = setInterval(moveImage,250);`) that moves the background image a pixel, then clear that interval (`clearInterval(interval);`) on `mouseLeave`.

I'll leave it to you to edit [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/georgedyer/XWnUA/2/) yourself and see if you can get it working how you want.

Comment: I tried option 1 by checking to see if mousePosX or mousePosY are < 10 or > 90. but it seems like the image is jumping . can't I do it with a smoother transition , like just panning the image from its position to  its edge ?

Comment: I made a fiddle for method #2, which I like better: http://jsfiddle.net/georgedyer/RRPsa/  ... you can set the scroll sensitivity/speed with the variable `scrollSpeed`

Comment: how can i add scroll speed to my original panning example ?